# NumberGroupSizes for "en-IN" culture in windows server 2012 is wrong

Tags: c#, windows-server-2012, cultureinfo

NumberGroupSizes for "en-IN" culture is set as 3,2,0 which is wrong and ideally be set as 3,2 in windows server 2012.

```
// Gets a NumberFormatInfo associated with the en-IN culture.
NumberFormatInfo nfi = new CultureInfo("en-IN", false).NumberFormat;

// Displays a value with the default separator (".").
Int64 myInt = 123456789012345;

Console.WriteLine(myInt.ToString("N", nfi));
```

The above code ran on windows server 2012 gives out put as 1234567890,12,345.00 which is wrong. Ideally it should be 12,34,56,78,90,12,345.00

Comment: Sounds annoying, but what's the _programming_ question?

Comment: I just edited the question with code details @MSalters

Comment: Looks much more like a question that can be answered. Unfortunately not by me, but StackOverflow has thousands of C# experts.

Comment: It is an operating system setting, configured with Control Panel > Language.

Comment: It looks like the issue with 2012 servers as it works all fine in other servers.

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind this is the values stored in `NumberFormatInfo.NumberGroupSizes` property. For culture "en-IN" this property has values `{3,2,0}` which means first group of the number left to the decimal point will have 3 digits, next group will be have 2 digits and rest of the number will not be grouped.

You can check by as running this code.

```
public static void Main()
{
    NumberFormatInfo nfi = new CultureInfo("en-IN", false).NumberFormat;

    Int64 myInt = 123456789012345;

    Console.WriteLine("NumberGroupSizes.Length : {0}", nfi.NumberGroupSizes.Length);
    for(var i = 0;i<nfi.NumberGroupSizes.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("NumberGroupSizes[{0}] : {1}", i, nfi.NumberGroupSizes[i]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(myInt.ToString("N",nfi));
```

If you create NumberFormatInfo using "en-US" culture it will have only one value in "NumberGroupSizes" property and that value is "3" so the output will divide the number in groups of 3 digits.

```
NumberFormatInfo nfi = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).NumberFormat;

Int64 myInt = 123456789012345;

Console.WriteLine(myInt.ToString("N", nfi));
// The output will 123,456,789,012,345.00
```

To solve your issue you need to set new values to the NumberGroupSizes property of the NumberFormatInfo as following.

```
public static void Main()
{
    NumberFormatInfo nfi = new CultureInfo("en-IN", false).NumberFormat;

    Int64 myInt = 123456789012345;

    int[] x = {3,2};
    nfi.NumberGroupSizes = x;
    Console.WriteLine(myInt.ToString("N",nfi));
    //The output will be 12,34,56,78,90,12,345.00
}
```

I hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: Thank you @Chetan but that is the question. Why it is set as 3,2,0 for en-IN? In all other servers its set as 3,2

Comment: That could be coz of the current number format setting and culture of the server. Did you see that difference between all other server and this server? Let me come back to you on this.

Comment: Yes, its different across all 2012 servers. 2008 servers works fine and even the local system settings matches with 2008 servers.

Comment: Really strange. All Windows 2012 servers are having this issue or only specific servers? Can you check what is set to "Digit Grouping" setting under "Control Panel > Clock, Language, and Region -> Additional Settings". This question now worth a bounty :)

Comment: I have checked in few windows server 2012 in my office. Also spinned a new VM in azure. All have the same issue.

Comment: I tried too on both 2008 R2 and 2012 Azure VMs. It works good on 2008 R2 but not on 2012. Looks like it's the issue with the OS not with the code.

Comment: I face the same issue with windows 8.1 machine. Please mark as answer as you get one:)

Comment: It seems this is very common, for me, I'm  having issues with the number of decimal digits in currency for culture es-CL. I haven't been able to find a solution though. If someone knows something, I will be very grateful

Comment: I have the similar problem with pt-BR culture for currency. The system default format on Windows Servers 2012 it´s different of others Windows OS versions. In my case, Windows Server 2012 uses "R$ 1,1" and others OS versions use "R$1,1". I tried to reset the culture on OS and tried useUserOverride: false to test.